# Zero out subarrays if sums don't match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given two Lists of integer arrays of the form:

```
genData = { {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}};
orgData = {{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {2,4,6,8}, {1,2,3,4}};
```

I'd like to determine if the sum of two subarrays at the same index in both lists don't match. If the sums match, do nothing. If the sums don't match, convert every integer in both subarrays into a 0.

For example, in the two lists above the subarrays at index 2 have a non-matching sum (10 vs 20). I'd like to convert the lists to

```
genData = { {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {0,0,0,0}, {1,2,3,4} };
orgData = { {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {0,0,0,0}, {1,2,3,4} };
```

I'm trying to first create a list if sums by trying

```
var genDataSum = genDataList.ForEach(x => x.Sum());
```

But obviously, that's throwing up errors..."Cannot assign void to an implicitly typed value".
Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with this syntax `{ [ ] }`. Is this actually c#? If so i think you want `{{}}`.

Comment: You are correct @JohnWu . I'm new to C# to my javascript tendencies are showing. I've edited the question to correct the syntax.

Comment: You're so close - try `Select` instead of `ForEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use select to get the sum. list.foreach works like normal for loop.

```
List<int[]> genData = new List<int[]>
    {
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };

List<int[]> orgData = new List<int[]>
    {
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };


var sumsGenData = genData.Select(a => a.Sum()).ToList();
var sumsOrgData = orgData.Select(a => a.Sum()).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < sumsGenData.Count; i++)
{
    if (sumsGenData[i] != sumsOrgData[i])
    {
        orgData[i] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` doesn't return anything. Use `Select`.

```
var orgData = { {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {0,0,0,0}, {1,2,3,4} };
var sums = orgData.Select( a => a.Sum() );
```